# using geom_textpath to add labels to a double donut chart , some labels color are smimilar with the fill color ,so not it's not clear

Tags: r, geom-text

I'm using geom_textpath to add labels to a double donut chart but there are some labels color are smimilar with the fill color ,so not it's not clear. How to handle it?

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

pie_data <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
  year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021),
  sales = c(40, 30, 20, 10, 15, 10)
)

pie_data %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = sales, fill = category)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 1, color = "white") +
  lims(x = c(2018, 2023)) +
  geom_textpath(
    position = position_fill(vjust = .5), angle = 90, alpha = 1,
    aes(
      color = factor(year),
      label = paste0(category, ":", sales)
    )
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the text color scale to make them stand out:

```r
pie_data %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = sales, fill = category)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 1, color = "white") +
  lims(x = c(2018, 2023)) +
  geom_textpath(
    position = position_fill(vjust = .5), angle = 90, alpha = 1,
    aes(
      color = factor(year),
      label = paste0(category, ":", sales)
    ), size = 6, fontface = 2
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("white", "yellow")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]